# The meaning of 'a resigned do-or-die look'

Tags: meaning

The passage below comes from Emily's runaway imagination by Beverly Cleary.

> Then one Sunday, when the store was closed and no one had banged on
>   the door to get Grandpa to open up, Grandpa and Grandma drove over to
>   the farm in the new Ford. Grandma was wearing her good serge suit and
>   her best hat. She had a ***resigned do-or-die*** look on her gentle face.

I'd like to ask the meaning of 'a ***resigned do-or-die*** look.'
It's not easy to figure out the meaning of the part in question because the two word ***resigned*** and ***do-or-die*** seems to contradict in meaning each other.
***Resigned*** means that grandma yield to grandpa's insistence to go on driving with his descendants. 
But the meaning for ***do-or-die*** in the dictionary says it means 'very determined'. 
So I cannot draw how the grandma looks in my mind.

Comment: She "resigned", as if  against her  will or preference (druthers),   to use a do-or-die look or expression. And I highly recommend *The Mouse and the Motorcycle* by the same author.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Clare, for your suggesting another great book for Beverly Cleary.

Comment: Morti, I would agree with you that these are somewhat contradictory descriptors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Resigned" is indeed a mood of capitulation or yielding to inevitability.  She's got no choice but to go along.

The "Do-or-die" expression means that she's going to devote her full efforts to getting through the experience.

A similar situation (and a possible model for her facial expression) might be someone saying "We're stuck with this cleaning job, so let's get it done."